# Phpstorm do not suggests apache modules?

Tags: apache, phpstorm

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.apache.php

How can i add them into the functions autocomplete? I have the 7.1 version

Comment: Or more generally, how does one add custom auto-complete hints to the editor?

Comment: @Jack yeah, could be useful

Comment: @Jack custom hints for what exactly?

Comment: @LazyOne Stuff like custom PECL extensions or sth.

Comment: @Jack For stuff like that (custom extensions) -- just create stub file **in PHP** (all declaration with comments but with empty bodies) and place in anywhere in the project -- all known to PhpStorm classes/constants/functions/etc are done in the same way. Just **Ctrl+Click** on any of them (e.g. `\Exception` and see how it's done). You can look at Phalcon framework -- it's done as extension (written in C) but it has separate stubs (dumb PHP code) just for IDE -- available as separate download/package on their site.

Comment: @Sam ... OK I have misread what you meant under "apache modules". **I did not follow the link (my mistake)** and I thought (was sure) you were talking about completion in `.htaccess` files, but you actually want PHP functions for Apache (e.g. `apache_get_modules()`). You can add them yourself -- see my previous comment addressed to Jack -- exactly the same can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you add something like that as an "external library" in your project.

In the project Tab right click on "External Libraries" and click "Configure PHP include paths".

To have something you can actually include here, you need to get the function definitions for the module. Here might composer be able to help you.